# Flutter - Show only one Dialog at the time

Tags: flutter, dart, dialog, flutter-web

I am working on a flutter application using several dialogs for several purposes.
In our code, there are some cases where the user can open a Dialog. Inside this dialog, there are some buttons that will also open another dialog. It results with 2 dialogs on top of each other and with a very dark background screen.
What we would like to do is to only display one dialog at the time. How can we achieve that ?

Here is a simple code to illustrate our issue:

```dart
class MyScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  build(BuildContext context) {
    return FlatButton(
      child: Text('Button'),
      onPressed: () async {
        final resultDialog = await showDialog<ResultDialog1>(
          context: context,
          builder: (BuildContext context) => MyFirstDialog(),
        );
        // Do some stuff with the result, so this part of the tree cannot be destroyed
      },
    );
  }
}

class MyFirstDialog extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  build(BuildContext context) {
    return FlatButton(
      child: Text('Button in first dialog'),
      onPressed: () async {
        final resultDialog = await showDialog<ResultDialog2>(
          context: context,
          builder: (BuildContext context) => MySecondDialog(),  // <- This will appear on top of the first dialog
        );
        // Do some stuff with the result, so this part of the tree cannot be destroyed
      },
    );
  }
}

class MySecondDialog extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text('Second Dialog');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

let me give you a widget for that

```dart
class MultiDialog extends StatefulWidget {
  final Widget child;

  const MultiDialog({Key key, this.child}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _MultiDialogState createState() => _MultiDialogState();

  static void addDialog(
      {@required BuildContext context, @required Widget dialog}) {
    assert(context != null, "the context cannot be null");
    assert(dialog != null, "the dialog cannot be null");
    context.findAncestorStateOfType<_MultiDialogState>()._addDialog(dialog);
  }

  static void remove({@required BuildContext context}) {
    assert(context != null, "the context cannot be null");
    context.findAncestorStateOfType<_MultiDialogState>()._remove();
  }
}

class _MultiDialogState extends State<MultiDialog> {
  final _allDialogs = <Widget>[];

  void _addDialog<T>(Widget dialog) {
    assert(dialog != null, "The dialog cannot be null");
    setState(() {
      _allDialogs.add(dialog);
    });
  }

  void _remove() {
    if (_allDialogs.isEmpty) {
      print("No dialogs to remove");
      return;
    }
    setState(() {
      _allDialogs.removeLast();
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        widget.child,
        if (_allDialogs.isNotEmpty) _allDialogs.last,
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

and when you want to add a dialog just call

```
MultiDialog.addDialog(
  context: context,
  dialog: AlertDialog(),
);
```

<strike>call `Navigator.pop` to remove the dialog, if there is another dialog which you pushed exist it will be shown, you can further pop them all with results, PS:this code isn't tested, let me know in the comments if this works for you</strike>

call `MultiDialog.remove(context:context)` to pop the visible dialog and bring back the previous dialog,

and if you receive a error that the addDialog is called on null, its because how flutter works, after `MultiDialog` use a `Builder`  to introduce a new `context` use it call `showDialog`,
**PS:ABOVE CODE IS TESTED**

Comment: I didn't manage to make it work. I have the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'Symbol(_addDialog)' of null`  and I think it is because the widget in the show dialog doesn't share the context as the previous screen (and therefore no `MultiDialog`) Also I feel like this code will not close the previous dialog when a new one is added right ?

Comment: yeah i over engineered previous one, check the new working code

Answer (score 0):

i made a stream out of the events that cause the dialog to pop up and used rx darts exhaust map to wait for the result (i was already using rxdart)

```
    dialogEventStream
    .exhaustMap((_) => maybeShowDialog().asStream())
    .listen((_) {});


  Future<bool> maybeShowOfflineModeDialog() async {
    final isOfflineModeEnabled = await _sharedPreferencesService.isOfflineModeEnabled();
    if (!isOfflineModeEnabled) {
      final isLoginOffline = await _navigationService.showDialog(NoConnectionDialog());
      if (isLoginOffline == true) {
        await _sharedPreferencesService.setIsOfflineModeEnabled(isOfflineModeEnabled: true);
        return await _navigationService.pushReplacement(AppShellOffline.routeName) ?? true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
```

something like this